# Using Excel: how can I change to colour of a cell based on whether 3 cells in the same row contain ANY text?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

sorry for the novice question. I have a spreadsheet looking for sign off from colleagues after reading a document. I would like cells in column 'O'(sign-off complete) to turn green if there has been any text entered in 3 cells in the specific row i.e. O3 to turn green if any text has been entered into L3 and M3 and N3 (only green if all of them have a value). I have tried conditional formatting with the formula `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISTEXT(L3:N3))>0, "Yes", "No")` - I hadn't got as far as working out how to change the colour, was just working on yes/no to start with!

I would really appreciate any advice, as this is definately not my usual area of work!

Many Thanks,
Laura

Comment: There are probably several ways. My first thought would be to =AND(  NOT(isblank(A1)),  NOT((isblank(A2)),  NOT(isblank(A3)) )  as a start.  That resolves to TRUE only if all three are filled.   Not tested on 21 though, I only have a more recent excel at hand.

Comment: Also, your sum scales better to multiple fields, but for maintenance I like the almost Engish version with the 'is not empty'. I guess that depends on the person and on if maintenance is needed.

Comment: Thank-you so much Hennes, not only for the fix but the explanation :) I appreciate your help :)